# PHP - Get MP4 location from video URL

Tags: php, python, video

I am trying to fetch FREE video courses from Udemy.

I have this link for example: https://www.udemy.com/new-lecture/view/?data=SlFCJUxYR34JQx55Xk5XPFAUTh4NDRsqWBQJe0wBAW5M

What I want to do is to fetch where the mp4 is located and embed it in one of my website pages.

I have a Chrome plugin that is able to download MP4 videos just by looking at the source page.

Is there a way to achieve the same with PHP or Python?
Remember I only need the video location not to download it.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl

Comment: Hi @NijrajGelani but this is going to download the video. I just need a way to know the URL of the MP4 source

Answer (score 2):

For embedding external videos, first make sure that you have the authorization to use the videos on your website otherwise you might face copyright issues.
Here is the php code to get the mp4 link:

```
<?php
$URL = "https://www.udemy.com/new-lecture/view/?data=SlFCJUxYR34JQx55Xk5XPFAUTh4NDRsqWBQJe0wBAW5M";
$Fetched_Contents = file_get_contents($URL);
if (preg_match('/<source(.*?)src="(.*?).mp4(.*?)"/i', $Fetched_Contents, $MP4_Link)){
    $Complete_MP4_Link = "{$MP4_Link[2]}.mp4{$MP4_Link[3]}";
    //now embed in your mp4 player using html,javascript
    echo $Complete_MP4_Link;
}else{
    echo "Didn't found any mp4 link.";
}
?>
```